# How to divide a SVG circle, depending of an external input?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, checkbox

I created a progressive circle that updates every time there's an interaction with a specific number of inputs, in this case it was 5 checkboxes. So as you can see in the `var percent` the number 20 was calculated by me because I knew I had 5 checkboxes.

```
//There are 5 checkboxes to interact with, so 100/5=20.
    var percent = (checked) * 20;

    myProgress.style.strokeDashoffset = 100 - percent;
```

Now I'm trying to do something similar, but this time the number of checkboxes to fill is unknown, it'll depend of the number of checkboxes that the user wants. So I decided to update my logic to something like this:

```js
function update() {

    var myProgress = document.getElementById("myProgress");
//Reference the Form.
    var toDo = document.getElementById("toDo");

//Reference all the CheckBoxes in Table.
    boxes = toDo.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
    checked = boxes.length

//Since in this case I don't know the number of checkboxes, I can't simply add the number 20, so I thought I could get that "20" by doing the following division.

    var division= [(100/checked.toFixed(4))];
    console.log("this is division:"+ division);

//and then with this division variable, replace the 20 from the previous code. But here is where I have the main problem, because as result of every click I do in a checkbox the var percent always get 100 and as result the ring is already fully colored.
    var percent = (checked) * (division);
    console.log("this is the percent:"+percent);

    myProgress.style.strokeDashoffset = 100 - percent;
    if (checked === 5) {
        myProgress.style.stroke= "#1DEBA1";
    }else if(checked < 5){
        myProgress.style.stroke= "purple"
    }
    return true;
}
checks = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
checks.forEach(function(box) {
    box.addEventListener("change", function() {
        update()
    });
});
```

```css
#myCircle {
  width: 0;
  height: 30px;
  stroke: #A3BBAD;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

#myProgress {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  stroke: #357266;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
   <svg height="100" width="100">
      <circle id="myProgress" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent"/>
      <circle id="myCircle" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent pathLength=100"/>
    </svg>
    <br>

    <form id="toDo">
      <input id="FirstToDo" type="checkbox" value="1" /><label for="FirstToDo">First</label>
      <input id="SecondToDo" type="checkbox" value="2" /><label for="SecondToDo">Second</label>
      <input id="ThirdToDo" type="checkbox" value="3" /><label for="ThirdToDo">Third</label>
      <input id="FourthToDo" type="checkbox" value="4" /><label for="FourthToDo">Fourth</label>
      <input id="FifthToDo" type="checkbox" value="5" /><label for="FifthToDo">Fifth</label>
    </form>
    <script src="Circle.js"></script>
```

Since in this case I don't know the number of checkboxes, I can't simply add the number 20, so I thought I could get that "20" by doing the following division.

```
    var division= [(100/checked.toFixed(4))];
    console.log("this is division:"+ division);
```

and then with this division variable, replace the 20 from the previous code. But here is where I have the main problem,  *as result of every click I do in a checkbox the var percent always returns 100 and as result the ring is already fully colored*.

```
    var percent = (checked) * (division);
    console.log("this is the percent:"+percent);

    myProgress.style.strokeDashoffset = 100 - percent;
```

Can somebody help me understand how can I made the var percent more precise, I know I'm mixing different types to get the result I want and most probably that is where my error is , but my problem is that I can't identify this mix of types interacting to each other, I'm not sure if the result I get from var division is considered a number, array or percent?

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to get the total number of all checkboxes for your division var and a seperate var for all currently checked boxes:

```
var checkBoxes = toDo.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
var checkBoxesChecked = toDo.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
```

```js
function update() {

  var myProgress = document.getElementById("myProgress");
  //Reference the Form.
  var toDo = document.getElementById("toDo");

  //Reference all the CheckBoxes in Table.
  var checkBoxes = toDo.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
  var checkBoxesChecked = toDo.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
  var checked = checkBoxesChecked.length

  //Since in this case I don't know the number of checkboxes, I can't simply add the number 20, so I thought I could get that "20" by doing the following division.

  var division = [(100 / checkBoxes.length.toFixed(4))];
  console.log("this is division:" + division);

  //and then with this division variable, replace the 20 from the previous code. But here is where I have the main problem, because as result of every click I do in a checkbox the var percent always get 100 and as result the ring is already fully colored.
  var percent = (checked) * (division);
  console.log("this is the percent:" + percent);

  myProgress.style.strokeDashoffset = 100 - percent;
  if (checked === 5) {
    myProgress.style.stroke = "#1DEBA1";
  } else if (checked < 5) {
    myProgress.style.stroke = "purple"
  }
  return true;
}
checks = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
checks.forEach(function(box) {
  box.addEventListener("change", function() {
    update()
  });
});
```

```css
#myCircle {
  width: 0;
  height: 30px;
  stroke: #A3BBAD;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

#myProgress {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  stroke: #357266;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  stroke-dasharray: 100 100;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
    <svg height="100" width="100">
        <circle id="myCircle" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent"/>
        <circle id="myProgress" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" pathLength="100" fill="transparent"/>
      </svg>
<br>

<form id="toDo">
  <input id="FirstToDo" type="checkbox" value="1" /><label for="FirstToDo">First</label>
  <input id="SecondToDo" type="checkbox" value="2" /><label for="SecondToDo">Second</label>
  <input id="ThirdToDo" type="checkbox" value="3" /><label for="ThirdToDo">Third</label>
  <input id="FourthToDo" type="checkbox" value="4" /><label for="FourthToDo">Fourth</label>
  <input id="FifthToDo" type="checkbox" value="5" /><label for="FifthToDo">Fifth</label>
</form>
```

**BTW:** I think you also need to set `pathLength="100"` to display you progress correctly. And your progress circle element needs to be on top of your background circle.